# Customizing the label of a daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using a bootstrap jquery daterangepicker in my project .it works fine but i need to change the label of its text box.

```
<input type="text" id="daterange" class="form-control" placeholder=" Select Date Range">
```

it's the code for my text box.

```
$('#daterange').daterangepicker(function(start, end, label) {
         console.log( start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') ); 
        });
```

in the text box it shows a date range like('11/16/2015 - 11/16/2015')i need to change it and initially the text box should display 'Select Date Range'

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the value of the input to your placeholder. Adding this line of code to you javascript will get you the desired effect

```
$('#daterange').val($('#daterange').attr("placeholder"));
```

Working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/wnh49mzq/3/